# How to find increasing subsequence of a list using recursion?

Tags: python, list

Given a list, I want to write a function that will return all the increasing subsequences of the list. The order doesn't matter.

E.g. inc_subseqs([1, 3, 2]) -> [[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2], [3]]

I have found a way like:

```
def insert_into_all(item, nested_list):
    """Assuming that nested_list is a list of lists, return a new list
    consisting of all the lists in nested_list, but with item added to
    the front of each.

    >>> nl = [[], [1, 2], [3]]
    >>> insert_into_all(0, nl)
    [[0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 3]]
    """
    return [[item] + el for el in nested_list]

def inc_subseqs(s):
    """Assuming that S is a list, return a nested list of all subsequences
    of S (a list of lists) for which the elements of the subsequence
    are strictly nondecreasing. The subsequences can appear in any order.

    >>> seqs = inc_subseqs([1, 3, 2])
    >>> sorted(seqs)
    [[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2], [3]]
    >>> inc_subseqs([])
    [[]]
    >>> seqs2 = inc_subseqs([1, 1, 2])
    >>> sorted(seqs2)
    [[], [1], [1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]
    """
    def subseq_helper(s, prev):
        if not s:
            return [[]]
        elif s[0] < prev:
            return subseq_helper(s[1:], prev)
        else:
            a = subseq_helper(s[1:], s[0])  # with first
            b = subseq_helper(s[1:], prev)  # without first
            return insert_into_all(s[0], a) + b
    return subseq_helper(s, 0)
```

However, I not getting how the else part of `subseq_helper` works and the general flow of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tree recursion problem.

prev stores the current maximum number of the returned list, and After the elif condition, we know s[0] >= prev.

Entering into the else condition, we know the result can be split into two parts, one includes s[0] and one does not, and these two parts share no common elements. We know subseq_helper(s[1:], prev) will produce a result r that has min(r) >= prev. Therefore, if we include s[0], it has to be the first element and we need to substitute prev to be s[0]. If we do not include s[0], then the prev argument remains unchanged. We then add the two results together.

Answer (score 0):

The else part works as follows:

Let's say initial seq,  s = s[0] s[1] s[2] s[3] ... s[n].
A subseq of seq s can be created from sequential combinations of any number of s[i] which can be picked from s[0] s[1] s[2] s[3] ... s[n],
e.g. s[0] s[1],  s[0] s[1] s[4],  s[0] s[7],  s[1] s[2] s[6],  s[2] s[3] s[5],  etc.
The set of all these subseqs can be separated or broken into two parts (or two subsets) as we intend it to be:
one subset A having all subseqs that start with s[0] (in other words, includes s[0]), and
the remaining subset B that doesn't start with s[0] (without s[0], just select within the remaining s[1:]).

Back to the problem, select all subseqs of s with non-decreasing constraint.
In subset **A**, each subseq starts with s[0], and the remaining subseqs of s[1:] must not have any member smaller than s[0], (non-decreasing). This leads to  **a** = subseq_helper(s[1:], s[0]).
To make them start with s[0] we apply the function insert_into_all, so now we get **A**.
The other set of subseqs that doesn't include s[0], i.e. subset **B**, doesn't need to be compared to s[0] because s[0] is excluded, but must be compared to prev to be non-decreasing.
That's why,   **b** = subseq_helper(s[1:], prev) , and we have **B** which is = b .
Hence, the else part returns  **A + B**  which is, insert_to_all(s[0],a) + b

---

The elif part:
Given a certain number prev, we want to find (or create) subseqs of s[0] s[1] ... s[n] with condition that s[0] must not be smaller than prev (we want it non-decreasing from prev) . If s[0] is smaller than prev, we skip s[0], and work with s[1:] (the remaining). Hence, return  subseq_helper(s[1:], prev).